# Shapefile to 2D grid as sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, geospatial, sparse-matrix, shapefile

I'm getting well and truly lost in all the bolt-on libraries for doing geospatial calculations with NumPy.

What is the *most straightforward* way to take a shapefile (whose extent is the entire Earth), and construct from it a sparse matrix that represents a latitude-longitude grid with a specified resolution, with matrix entries 1 at all grid points within the shapefile's polygons, 0 elsewhere?

I know how to read in a shapefile using GeoPandas or Fiona; where I get stuck is the "convert to a sparse matrix" part.  "Rasterization" seems to require yet another bolt-on, not give me control over the grid resolution, and not be able to spit out anything other than TIFFs, which is less than useful.

Comment: do you need to do it many times or could you just use a GIS to do it once and import that raster output into python/numpy?

Comment: I only need to do it once, but my experience with standalone GISes so far has been "none of them work", so I'd *prefer* to stick to NumPy and friends.

Comment: You could ask on Gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

1. Create empty sparse matrix
2. Write a function to send a random point to a "small" set of points
3. For each polygon, sample all points in the bounding box uniformly. For each point that falls into the Polygon, apply above function to get standard `key` and update the sparse matrix with the key and value of 1.

I not sure if it falls under straightforward category, but it can be done in python with `osgeo` and `scipy`. Of course, sampling will be very slow if you have large polygons, but since you are using a sparse matrix I assume this will not be an issue. You can adjust the resolution and play with projections within osgeo as well.

```
from itertools import product
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix
import numpy as np

# https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook
from osgeo import ogr

# DATA:
# http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/

SHP_FNAME = 'ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp'

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
data = driver.Open(SHP_FNAME, 0)
layer = data.GetLayer()

XDIAM = 360.0
YDIAM = 180.0
XRES = YRES = 10 ** 2
dX = XDIAM / XRES
dY = YDIAM / YRES

def to_key(pt):
    x, y = pt
    x -= x % dX - XDIAM / 2
    y -= y % dY - YDIAM / 2
    return (x / dX, y / dY)

def geom_to_keys(g):
    xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = g.GetEnvelope()
    print xmax, ymax, xmin, ymin
    xs = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, (xmax - xmin) / dX)
    ys = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, (ymax - ymin) / dY)
    for x, y in product(xs, ys):
        point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
        point.AddPoint(x, y)
        if g.Contains(point):
            yield to_key((x, y))

smatrix = dok_matrix((XRES + 1, YRES + 1), np.int8)

one = np.int8(1)

for feature in layer:
    geom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    if geom.Area() > 1000:
        continue
        # sampling is slow for large polygons

    for key in geom_to_keys(geom):
        smatrix.update({
            key : one,
            })

if XRES * YRES < 10 ** 6 + 1:
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    plt.pcolor(smatrix.toarray().transpose())
    plt.show()
```

Here is a picture; I omitted a few large countries to speed things up.

[image]